# Getting the "str" has no property "_default_manager" on a Django app just on startup

Tags: python, django, apache

Right after I restart Apache to pick up the new Django changes, I get the following errors for probably 30 seconds to a minute afterwards:

`ViewDoesNotExist: Tried home_page in module project.app.views. Error was: 'str' object has no attribute '_default_manager'`

The errors go away after a bit, but it's very odd. Any idea how to debug this or what might be causing it?

Comment: `_default_manager` is an attribute of a model class. Any 'str' you object in your view which you are using as a model class by mistake? Maybe you add some code of view here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's this bug:

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10405#comment:11

Seems like a perfect fit considering google searches don't show much else, and that your problem goes away after some time - according to this ticket due to lazy loading of model strings.

The comment suggests adding the following before your admin autodiscover function.

```
from django.db.models.loading import cache as model_cache
if not model_cache.loaded:
    model_cache.get_models()
```

Comment: Definitely seems like this is the problem, thanks, I think that'll do the trick. As a note for later, my issue isn't related to the admin.autodiscover() bit, but it does occur with ModelForm imports. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am newbie to Django python, my mistake was in view.py, model part

model = ‘Article'

```
ArticleListViews(ListView):
    model = 'Article'
    template_name = ‘article.html'
```

it raise same error. `model = Article` is correct. I don’t need to put the name of model in quotations.

enjoy coding.