# Django Modelform giving isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Getting the following error on a specific view:

```
isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    ***********CHANGED FOR PRIVACY
Django Version:     1.3
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py in get_default, line 867
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
```

The same view is not giving any error on my local development environment.
This site is deployed on Amazon Ec2 running apache.

This is the exact code which is throwing the exception:
`form = MyCustomModelForm() # An unbound form`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strange coincidence, but I believe your problem is closely related [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775178/getting-the-str-has-no-property-default-manager-on-a-django-app-just-on-star).

I would try the same solution posted there: force `get_models` before your ModelForm.

```
from django.db.models.loading import cache as model_cache
if not model_cache.loaded:
    model_cache.get_models()
```

Is your `ModelForm` perhaps instantiated in a location where your model's related apps have yet to finish loading?

Here's another example: this person has a middleware accessing a model with a foreign key string before the string has been resolved to an object, and has the same issues with it appearing only on apache -- according to him because the dev environment runs `get_models()` first - didn't know.

http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/msg/d1482a2eba45e498?dmode=source

Comment: I am gonna try this out. I am not using admin function so the admin auto discover is not where it goes wrong. Curious that if i would use auto discover if i would get the same error.

Comment: Yup, I can reproduce your error if I have a model defined earlier in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list that refers to a model further down the line via a foreign key string and I instantiate the model class. Hopefully that's the problem!

Comment: It was! You are amazing! I wouldn't figure out the link of the problem with model forms and admin autodiscover. Maybe if I knew the internals a little more.

Comment: I had this problem in django shell. I've put the model_cache.get_models()  in both models.py , tweaked ISTALLED_APPS and i could not get rid of this. The only thing that helped was to import both apps before instatiating required class : from app1.models import Cls1 ; from app2.import Cls2 ; a = Cls2()

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
self.assertIsInstance(Inst,pywbem.cim_obj.CIMInstance,"input Instance {} is not a CIMInstance object".format(Inst))
```