# Django FieldError only with debug disabled

Tags: django, server-error

I've got a Django project that throws me "FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'game' into field. Choices are: [list of choices]".

The funny thing is, it only occurs when DEBUG is disabled in settings.py. When DEBUG is enabled everything seems to work fine.

I have identified the code that triggers the error. My model looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from time import strftime
from rostermaker.models import Player
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils import timezone

class Game(models.Model):
    when = models.DateTimeField(unique = True)
    opponent = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default="TBD")
...

    def __unicode__(self):
        when = timezone.localtime(self.DateTime)
        return when.strftime('%a, %b %d, %Y %I:%M %p')

class Stat(models.Model):
    g = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name = 'stat_game')
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name = 'stat_player', limit_choices_to={'active': True})
...
```

In admin.py, the .count and .filter lines trigger the error:

```
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        count = obj.players.count()
        women = obj.players.filter(sex='F')
        women_count = women.count()
        if count != 0:
            women_pct = int((women_count/float(count))*100)
            self.message_user(request,"Players scheduled: %s | Women: %s percent" % (count, women_pct))
        else:
            self.message_user(request,"Players scheduled: 0 | Women: 0 percent")
```

In a couple of views, lines similar to this one cause the error:

```
played_games_list = Game.objects.filter(DateTime__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-when')
```

I'm using Django version 1.4 and PostgreSQL 8.4.20.

My best guess from what I've read here is that the Game class isn't loading properly. But why it appears to load properly when DEBUG is on mystifies me.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Traceback, as requested:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
   response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 366, in wrapper
   return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
   response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 89, in _wrapped_view_func
   response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 196, in inner
   return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/utils/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapper
   return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
   response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/utils/decorators.py", line 21, in bound_func
   return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/db/transaction.py", line 224, in inner
   return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 955, in add_view
   self.save_model(request, new_object, form, False)

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/myproject/rostermaker/admin.py", line 69, in save_model
   count = obj.players.count()

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/manager.py", line 119, in count
   return self.get_query_set().count()

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 567, in get_query_set
   return super(ManyRelatedManager, self).get_query_set().using(db)._next_is_sticky().filter(**self.core_filters)

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/query.py", line 624, in filter
   return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/query.py", line 642, in _filter_or_exclude
   clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1250, in add_q
   can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1122, in add_filter
   process_extras=process_extras)

File "/home/bwareham/webapps/mprsb/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1316, in setup_joins
   "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(names)))

FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'game' into field. Choices are: Hall of Fame, active, alias, battingchamps, bombat, captains, firstName, goldengloves, id, lastName, mostimproved, mvp, photo, rookies, roster, sex, walker, whippet

Comment: Probably not be causing your problem, but it might not be a good idea to use DateTime as a variable name.

Comment: I'd look for lines where 'game' is a part of the filter, that would cause an error like you mention, but without a traceback I can't see much.

Comment: Full error stack please.

Comment: Traceback added to original post.

Comment: DateTime removed as variable (replaced by 'when'). It didn't change FieldError behavior, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: Renamed variable 'game' in Stat class to 'g'. That seems to have fixed the field error on the site's front end - I assume I had a conflict with the Game class. But I'm still getting the error on admin pages when I try to save or access a Game object. (Only with DEBUG=False.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some sort of loading problem. Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775178/getting-the-str-has-no-property-default-manager-on-a-django-app-just-on-sta/5775386#5775386).

Am able to force model loading with this snippet before the admin autodiscover function in urls.py:

```
from django.db.models.loading import cache as model_cache
if not model_cache.loaded:
    model_cache.get_models()
```

Thanks to all who tried to help me troubleshoot. I always learn something.